# Strange scrolling bugs with video header background HTML5

Tags: css, video, background, html5-video

Here is the link to my test site: http://s209381.gridserver.com/

When scrolling sometimes the video loads before the section over top of it loads which makes the whole experience pretty glitchy. I've played around with the z-index but doesn't seem to have helped much. Not super familiar with video backgrounds so not sure what to try.

Would love any suggestions - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What video are you referring to? There is no video displayed... Anyhow, the order of the elements determines when they load. Top being first and bottom being last. Maybe you are loading your video too early? You can arrange the order to fix and use css to keep it in the right place.